# Laravel controllers with roles

Tags: php, laravel, roles

I have an application which will be a SaaS and is utilizing user roles. Of course, controllers will need to forward different data depending on user roles or permissions, however I think this approach may lead me to huge controllers and I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do this? For example my user create method:

```
public function create()
{
    if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
        $clinics = Clinic::pluck('name', 'id');
        $roles = Role::pluck('display_name', 'id');
    }
    else{
        $clinics = Clinic::where('id', Auth::user()->clinic_id)->get()->pluck('name', 'id');
        $roles = Role::where('name', '!=', 'admin')->get()->pluck('display_name', 'id');
    }

    $states = State::pluck('name', 'id');
    $cities = City::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('users.create', compact('user', 'clinics', 'states', 'cities', 'roles'));
}
```

Which is okay now when I only implemented admin and non-admin user, but when roles get complicated, is there a cleaner way to assemble this?

Comment: You can go with model repositories and move the user role check into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look to the [Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#query-scopes) of the Laravel Documentation. You can attach the scopes to your models to achieve the same results.

This solution will not help you deleting code complexity (that is moved in models) but will help you remove code duplication because you will encounter the same "if" multiple times during the development of your application...

A local scope for your clinics could be like this one

```
class Clinic extens Model {
    [...]
    public function scopeCanSee($query)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if(!$user->isAdmin())
            return $query->where('id', $user->clinic_id);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

and in your controller you can then filter the results in this way

```
public function create()
{
    $clinics = Clinic::canSee()->pluck('name', 'id');
    [...]

    $states = State::pluck('name', 'id');
    $cities = City::pluck('name', 'id');

    return view('users.create', compact('user', 'clinics', 'states', 'cities', 'roles'));
}
```

### Global Scopes

Another way is to use the Global Scopes (but I haven't tested them)

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new RolesScope);
    }
}
class Clinic extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new ClinicsScope);
    }
}
```

and scopes similar to

```
class ClinicsScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $builder->where('id', $user->clinic_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would still have to duplicate the code across my models if I want to filter only by ID though, right?

Comment: Can you explain me exactly what you mean?

Comment: @Norgul you can pass parameters to scopes, so you can reuse a single scope for different ids.

Comment: For example, your `scopeCanSee()` function works now for `Clinic`. If I were to do the same type of filtering (so that only admins can see full list) on `OtherModel`, I would copy the same function on `OtherModel`. Is there a way to avoid duplication?

Comment: If the attribute you want to filter is always the same, you can apply the same Global Scope (in my previous example was different due to your question).